Spring Boot MongoDB Driver Upgrade Causes IndexOptionsConflict with Javers
Here’s a refined version of your issue to post on Stack Overflow for better clarity and context:

Title: Spring Boot MongoDB Driver Upgrade Causes IndexOptionsConflict with Javers
Body:
We recently upgraded our Spring Boot application from version 2.5.x to the latest 3.x version, along with the MongoDB driver upgrade from 3.5.x to 4.11.x. Our application uses Javers for auditing, and we have encountered the following issue after the upgrade:
In the earlier setup (Spring Boot 2.5 and MongoDB driver 3.5.x), Javers used a collection named jv_snapshot with an index name:
commitMetadata.properties.key_1_commitMetadata.properties.value_1

After upgrading the MongoDB driver to 4.11.x, the index name for the same collection has changed to:
commitMetadata.properties_key_value

If the old index (commitMetadata.properties.key_1_commitMetadata.properties.value_1) exists in the database, the application throws the following error on startup:
(IndexOptionsConflict): 'Index with name: commitMetadata.properties_key_value already exists with a different name' on server xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.

When we delete the old index manually, the application works fine because the Spring Boot Javers starter automatically creates the new index (commitMetadata.properties_key_value). However, we want to avoid manually deleting the index to ensure smooth deployment in all environments.
Steps Tried:

Deleting the old index fixes the issue, but this isn't an ideal solution for production environments.
Ensuring compatibility between Javers and the MongoDB driver.

Error Details:
(IndexOptionsConflict): 'Index with name: commitMetadata.properties_key_value already exists with a different name' on server xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Full Response: {"raw": {"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx": {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Index with name commitMetadata.properties_key_value already exists with a different name", "code": 85, "codeName": "IndexOptionsConflict", ...}}

Environment:

Spring Boot: 3.x
MongoDB Driver: 4.11.x
Javers: Latest version compatible with Spring Boot 3.x

Question:
How can we resolve this issue without manually deleting the old index? Is there a way to handle this programmatically or configure Javers/Spring Boot to handle this migration seamlessly?
